How to extract date from a column in Pandas?
I am trying to extract only dates from a column(Result) of a dataframe. Dates will only start from year 2000 and beyond but the format of date could be any including datetime.
What I want is just date.
Is there a simple way of doing it with some easy Regex codes ?
Example of dataset:
date_extract_df = pd.DataFrame({
'Result':[': XYZ',': 39 YRS/M',': Self',': HOME COLLECTION',': 10593974',
           ': 012408030006',': 03/08/2024',': 03/Aug/2024 11:50 AM',': 03/Aug/2024 03:24 PM',
            ' ','31.80','15'],
 'Unit':['dfd','dfdfd','tytyt','03/08/2024','fgf','tyt','xcx','ere','sds','03/Aug/2024 03:24 PM',
        '4545','5656']
})

Expected Result:

    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6 03/08/2024
    7 03/Aug/2024
    8 03/Aug/2024
    9 03/Aug/2024
    10
    11

I am not good at Regex and have tried below code:
date_extract_df.Result.str.extract(r"^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$")
Is there a way to figure out Rows containing dates in the column and then filter that row to extract date ?
I was trying this for a similar approach:
datetime.datetime.isoformat(date_check['Result'][9])
date_check['Result'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.isoformat(x))

What is your expected results?

@PraysonW.Daniel I have updated Post with expected Result.

pd.to_datetime(date_extract_df["Result"].str.replace(": ",""), errors="coerce") does all minus the epoch one

@PraysonW.Daniel Yes this will work for me for now but I am not sure how generic it will stay as the data could be anything and I just want dates from it

As long as they are not epochs, so  pandas will try to convert them. You can use another tool like dateparser to ensure that you can change anything

@PraysonW.Daniel that sounds good then. Please add your code to the Answer so that I can accept it and close this Post. Thanks alot for helping me out. Really Appreciate your help in explaining me things and giving me alternatives.

Minus the epoch time (line 6), this should do the task
pd.to_datetime(date_extract_df["Result"].str.replace(": ",""), errors="coerce")

To go deeper, you can use third-parties tools like dateparser to cover more cases
